# How does youtube transcript to subtitle synchronization work?

Tags: youtube, subtitle, transcription

Youtube has a feature where you can submit every thing that is being spoken in the video as text and youtube will autosync that transcript into subtitles automatically.
Is voice recognition is used or they figure out sync by audio spectrum displacements. There are several similar services online as well.

How is such a system can be developed?